# What is the secure option in Node.js Connect session() params

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, connect, javascript-framework, middleware

I'm working through the following `Connect` example:

```
var connect = require ('connect');
var timeout = 30000; // session timeout: 30 seconds
var sessionOpts = {
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    key: 'myapp_sid',
    cookie: { maxAge: timeout, secure: true} /*Example doesn't work with secure?*/
};

var app = connect ()
    .use (connect.favicon())
    .use (connect.cookieParser ('keyboard cat'))
    .use (connect.session(sessionOpts))
    .use (function (req, res, next) {
        var sess = req.session;
        if (sess.views) {
            res.setHeader ('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.write ('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>');
            res.end();
            sess.views++;
        } else {
            sess.views = 1;
            res.end ('welcome to the session demo. refresh!');
        }
    })
    .listen (3000);
```

When I go to the site, if the cookie option does not include `secure: true` then the number of views is incremented and reset after 30 seconds.  When I include the secure option the session no longer stays around for 30 seconds, it resets every refresh.

What is the secure option for and how can I use it with `Connect`'s session middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `secure` parameter sets the [secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) for HTTP cookies:

> The purpose of the secure flag is to prevent cookies from being observed by unauthorized parties due to the transmission of a the cookie in clear text.
>   To accomplish this goal, browsers which support the secure flag **will only send cookies with the secure flag when the request is going to a HTTPS page**. Said in another way, **the browser will not send a cookie with the secure flag set over an unencrypted HTTP request.**

In your case, the secure cookie is likely not being sent at all, because you are not serving your page over HTTPS.